# UninitializedPropertyAccessException while working with lateinit

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-debug

I'm working on Android development using Kotlin, and encountering an issue with a lateinit var named polyline. The error I'm getting suggests that even though I assigned a value to polyline inside a function called from the onCreate, the app is still crashing with the message that polyline has not been initialized.

Pls how do I go about this? Is there something I'm missing?

See the code below. I removed all unneccessary codes for this question

```
class CustomerMapActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback {

    private lateinit var polyline: String


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityCustomerMapBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val pickUpLocation = "Hall 2 Car Park, Benin City, Nigeria"
        val dropOffLocation = "Nadia Bakery, Benin City, Nigeria"
        val apiKey = R.string.google_api_key.toString()

        routesDetails(pickUpLocation, dropOffLocation, apiKey)


    }


    override fun onMapReady(mMap: GoogleMap) {
        
        drawRouteOnMap()

    }


    private fun routesDetails(origin: String, destination: String, apiKey: String){

        val routeService = ServiceBuilder.buildService(RouteService::class.java)

        val requestCall = routeService.getRoutes(origin, destination, apiKey)
        requestCall.enqueue(object: Callback<RoutesResponse> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<RoutesResponse>, response: Response<RoutesResponse>) {

                if (response.isSuccessful) {

                    if (routeResponse != null && routeResponse.routes.isNotEmpty()){


                        polyline = response.body()?.routes?.get(0)?.overview_polyline?.points.toString()

                    }else{
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<RoutesResponse>, t: Throwable) {

            }

        })
    }



    private fun drawRouteOnMap() {
        val decodedPolyline = PolyUtil.decode(polyline)
        
    }
```

Logcat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: leoh.portcustomer, PID: 24494
                                                                                                    kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property polyline has not been initialized
                                                                                                        at leoh.portcustomer.activities.CustomerMapActivity.drawRouteOnMap(CustomerMapActivity.kt:162)
                                                                                                        at leoh.portcustomer.activities.CustomerMapActivity.onMapReady(CustomerMapActivity.kt:104)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.maps.zzat.zzb(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.1.0:1)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzar.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.1.0:6)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.maps.zzb.onTransact(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.1.0:3)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:1043)
                                                                                                        at m.ff.c(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@232617040@23.26.17 (150700-0):8)
                                                                                                        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.bg.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@232617040@23.26.17 (150700-0):19)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Tried resolving it but wasnt still working.
I'll appreciate your asistance

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused because the function `drawRouteOnMap()` uses the variable `polyline` before it is initialized, since you declared it `lateinit`. This means you have to use the function `drawRouteOnMap()` only **after** `polyline` has a value.

In **this** piece of code you provided, moving / calling again the `drawRouteOnMap()` immediately after

`polyline = response.body()?...`

should solve your problem, like this:

```
val requestCall = routeService.getRoutes(origin, destination, apiKey)
requestCall.enqueue(object: Callback<RoutesResponse> {
    override fun onResponse(call: Call<RoutesResponse>, response: Response<RoutesResponse>) {

        if (response.isSuccessful) {

            if (routeResponse != null && routeResponse.routes.isNotEmpty()){


                polyline = response.body()?.routes?.get(0)?.overview_polyline?.points.toString()

                drawRouteOnMap()
            }else{
                ....
```

Keep in mind that since there is more code other than this, using the function `drawRouteOnMap()` in the response **could not** suit your case. By doing that it may generate others errors.

The [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html#late-initialized-properties-and-variables) helps also checking if a variable is initialized or not, have a look.

If this doesn't help, please let me know and I'll provide more support, happy coding!

Comment: thanks alot. I did as you said, it worked but this time, the route drawn wasn't fully shown on the screen, it appeared cut off probably has a connection to the override onMapReady function

Comment: Yep I told you there could be some problems after @kosi

Comment: can you help me out?

Comment: I would need the entire code to help you find a solution @kosi

Comment: how can i get that to you?

Comment: You could copy paste fully in your question by editing it